# How to use GROUP BY in a Query with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

assuming i have the SQL Query below (`Notice the JOIN`):

```
SELECT
    bpq.Id,
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.PartId,
    bpq.Hkid
FROM
    BoxPartsQuantity bpq
JOIN
    Batch b
ON
    bpq.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE 
    PartId = 1
```

and that the returned result is:

```
Id     BatchCode    PartId  Hkid
137    2016-03-31   1       34361
138    2016-03-31   1       34361
139    2016-03-31   1       34361
140    2016-03-31   1       34361
141    2016-03-31   1       34361
1123   2016/04/19   1       34361
1976   2016/04/29   1       34361
```

How can I remove the duplicates in `BatchCode` and `Hkid` assuming that i want the result like below:

```
Id     BatchCode    PartId  Hkid
137    2016-03-31   1       34361
1123   2016/04/19   1       34361
```

I've tried the code below:

```
SELECT
    bpq.Id,
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.PartId,
    bpq.Hkid
FROM
    BoxPartsQuantity bpq
JOIN
    Batch b
ON
    bpq.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE 
    PartId = 1

GROUP BY
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.Hkid
```

but it returns me with this error:

> ```
> [SQL]SELECT
>   bpq.Id,
>   b.BatchCode,
>   bpq.PartId,
>   bpq.Hkid
> FROM
>   BoxPartsQuantity bpq
> JOIN
>   Batch b
> ON
>   bpq.BatchId = b.Id
> WHERE 
>   PartId = 1
>
> GROUP BY
>   b.BatchCode,
>   bpq.Hkid
> ```
>
> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Column 'BoxPartsQuantity.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm very confused on what i should and must do, as I am not that much knowledgeable with SQL Coding and all. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an aggregate function for the records not participating in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    MIN(bpq.Id),
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.PartId,
    bpq.Hkid
FROM
    BoxPartsQuantity bpq
JOIN
    Batch b
ON
    bpq.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE 
    PartId = 1    
GROUP BY
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.Hkid,
    bpq.PartId
```

The above query places also field `bpq.PartId` in the `GROUP BY`. This doesn't have any effect in the grouping, since `PartId=1` for all the records returned. Using `MIN` for field `bpq.Id` the query returns the minimum value per `b.BatchCode, bpq.Hkid` group of records, as in the expected result cited in the OP.

Comment: @TheQuestioner In this case you have to remove `bpq.Hkid` from the `GROUP BY` clause and add something like `MIN(bpq.Hkid)` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring since  `bpq.id` is not unique, there are multiple values for each group so you have to choose which one of them your want(not in all DBMS though, MySQL allows it and it will randomly choose a value) .

By your example I suppose you want the first `ID` , so `MIN()` is the the way to go:

```
SELECT
    min(bpq.Id),
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.PartId,
    bpq.Hkid
FROM
    BoxPartsQuantity bpq
JOIN
    Batch b
ON
    bpq.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE 
    PartId = 1
GROUP BY
    b.BatchCode,
    bpq.Hkid,
    bpq.PartId
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
SELECT
distinct min(bpq.Id) over(partition by b.BatchCode,bpq.Hkid),
b.BatchCode,
bpq.PartId,
bpq.Hkid

FROM
BoxPartsQuantity bpq
JOIN
Batch b
ON
bpq.BatchId = b.Id
WHERE bpq.PartId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have faced tells that, each column in Select column's list that does not included in aggregate function should be placed in Group By too.

to cover your requirement beside the @Giorgos Betsos answer, you can also use Row_Number that do not need to use Group By any more as follow too:

```
SELECT  Id ,
    BatchCode ,
    PartId ,
    Hkid
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY b.BatchCode ORDER BY bpq.Id ) AS Rn ,
                bpq.Id ,
                b.BatchCode ,
                bpq.PartId ,
                bpq.Hkid
      FROM      BoxPartsQuantity bpq
                JOIN Batch b ON bpq.BatchId = b.Id
      WHERE     PartId = 1
    ) AS K
WHERE   Rn = 1;
```

In the above query and inside sub-query we first assign row number for each records. This row number is reseted for each different BatchCode, and this row number will be ordered based on Id column. After assigning row number, we filter the row number to be equal to 1 in outer query. Reason that we used sub query to assign row number  and filter it in outer query is that, Row_number can not be placed inside Where part of query.